# Ubuntu 20.04 - flash or blink of a native dekstop background or color

Tags: 20.04, themes, .desktop

I've changed my desktop background in settings, but every time system is loading just before desktop shows up with my custom background there is a flash or a blink of native background or a background color (I'm not sure). Anybody has this effect? I had this problem in ubuntu 14.04 as well and I had to change background in two different places, how about 20.04 is there a file I need to change manually for my custom background or if this is a matter of some color then a black color would be fine in my situation, where is this being changed?